# how to average standard deviations of independent groups

Tags: variance, standard-deviation, mean

I have means and standard deviations on a given variable, $X$, for six independent samples of unequal sample sizes:

Group 1: $SD = 0.96 , n = 290$
Group 2: $SD = 1.082, n = 250$
Group 3: $SD = 0.70, n = 250$
Group 4: $SD = 0.794, n = 310$
Group 5: $SD = 0.819, n = 290$
Group 6: $SD = 0.691, n = 190$

total sample size = $1,580$

I am asked to report the the average standard deviation based on these values, so, in essence, I am looking to compute the average standard deviation based on six independent datasets - that is, an average of six separate standard deviations (*not* the combined standard deviation for the total sample).

Can I just calculate the weigthed mean of all six standard deviations, with the weights for each sample given its sample size divided by total sample size of all six samples combined?

So, in essence, producing the following:
average standard deviation = $\frac{[(\frac{290}{1,580}\cdot0.96) + (\frac{250}{1,580}\cdot1.082)+(\frac{250}{1,580}\cdot0.70)+..continued for all six groups..)]}{6}?$

Thank you!

Comment: Exactly what is this "average standard deviation" intended to represent?  The reason I ask is that there are (infinitely) many kinds of averages, so the solution is not determined solely from the need to average these values: it is determined primarily by how the average needs to be related to the quantities that contribute to it.  For instance, why shouldn't we take (say) the weighted mean of the *variances* (the squares of the SDs) and then take the square root of that?

Comment: You're welcome, Kristi--but it doesn't count as an answer; not here, anyway: it's a request that you clarify or amplify your question.  Our hope is that you will thereby eventually get a more appropriate answer for your needs and future readers will have better information, too.

Comment: I hit "enter" too fast :)

I actually meant to write you wrote in your last sentences - I am asked to calculate the weighted mean of the variances and then take the square root of those. Literally, I want to calculate an average variance that represents the mean variation of the target variable based on the variances of all six samples (they can be considered independent subsamples). So, in essence, how does variable vary, on average, within the six samples.

Comment: In other words, it sounds like you want to combine the samples in order to obtain a *standard error of the mean,* assuming the samples are independent.  However you wish to ask it, you need to edit your question to reflect this need--comments can disappear at any time and not everybody reads them.

Comment: No, I don't want to combine the samples in the traditional sense. I will re-phrase the question as you asked but I am not sure how I can be clearer in terms of what I am looking for.

Comment: I think I see: the language you have used about "variation of the target variable" may be understood ambiguously as meaning "standard error of estimate of the mean" or else "sample-to-sample variation in the mean."  Please note that the latter is not any kind of average of the standard deviations and cannot even be computed from them. (Given that the sample sizes are different, measuring the "sample-to-sample variation in the standard deviation"--a third interpretation--would seem to have little meaning, but again that cannot be estimated just from the individual standard deviations.)

Comment: So is the formula I provided adequate?

Comment: No, because it addresses none of the questions I have raised.  You haven't supplied enough information for people to know what kind of "average" is needed or what it is intended to mean.

Comment: The question is not sufficiently unambiguous to offer any reasonable answer. What are you using this calculation for? [What population quantity does it represent? What assumptions are you making, or prepared to make?]

Comment: Perhaps the way forward is to go back to the person who asked you to do this and ask them to clarify what they meant because it is not clear to any of us what purpose they had in mind.